# What is the difference between SQL Server Compact Edition and SQL Server Express Edition?

Tags: sql-server-express, relational-database, database-engine

Can someone please explain what is the main difference between SQL Server Compact Edition and SQL Server Express Edition?

For what purpose I should use this or that one?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This [blog](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/22/sql-server-difference-between-sql-server-compact-edition-ce-and-sql-server-express-edition/) has everything you need, it will even give you a feature comparison.

If you don't feel like reading, SQL Server Compact is for Mobile/Embeded Apps, and Express edition is just a free scaled down SQL Server standard.

**Edit** 
A very important thing to point out as @Rup just stated is that Compact is an in memory database.

Comment: To highlight the important bit: Express installs as a service on the machine (c.f. mysql) whereas Compact runs in-process in your app (c.f. sqlite).

Comment: @Rup, would Compact also run on a Desktop machine, being just an in-process DB? AFAIK Compact is for Mobile devices only.

Answer (score 3):

Express is a fully functional, albeit size-limited (4GB for 2008/2005, 10GB for 2008 R2) version of sql server.  In my experience, it is mostly intended for development.  Generally speaking, if you want to deploy your SQL Express database to a hosting environment, you must import to a SQL Server database (e.g., GoDaddy).  Most hosting providers will not allow you to attach a sql express database from the app_data folder at run time.

Compact Edition can be deployed as a stand-alone, embedded database for client apps.  Note that the CE version has multi-threading issues that prevent it from being deployed to a web application.  There's a reference to this on Scott Gu's blog...I'll see if I can find it.

Edit: Here you are.  You need to wait for version 4 to deploy to ASP.Net web site:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/06/30/new-embedded-database-support-with-asp-net.aspx

If you want to deploy an embedded database with a web app, System.Data.SQLite is your man...